# Protractor - Run code before each test and after each test

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I need to run some code before every single test.
This could be a easy solution if I would have a single spec file e.g. `main.e2e.ts` but making one spec file for huge applications sounds too dirty.

I separated my tests to multiple spec files (e.g. `login.e2e.ts` & `dashboard.e2e.ts`) but I want to run some code before each and after each `it` no matter of spec file.

I found out that it is possible with `beforeEach(() => {}` and `afterEach(() => {}` and I'm doing it right now in every single file. But I believe there have to be some prettier solution for this approach.

Is there a way to run code before and after each `it` while using multiple spec files?

Comment: You can have a `beforeEach` and `afterEach` outside the outermost `describe`s, that will run for every test.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe sorry but I'm not sure how you mean it. Doesn't it force me to merge all test files to single one anyway? If I'm wrong can you provide some example?

Comment: No, you can put a `setup.e2e.ts` that literally just contains the top-level before/after each/all.

Comment: I maybe miss something but if I create new `setup.e2e.ts` and will execute this as first test. And then run `login.e2e.ts`  that `beforeEach` will not do anything in `login.e2e.ts` right?

Comment: The top level beforeeach \ aftereach functions will always run before and after any tests in any of the spec files. They will become available in a global scope. Also if you have any other before\after functions in your login class they will also be called in the order - common before each -> login before each -> TEST -> login after each -> login after each... Do remember to include this file in the specs parameter in config file. One downside is in the console it shows up as an extra spec but with no tests in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have common and shared before and after methods, you could write it to a common file. Then import those functions to the spec file and call them in your `beforeEach`, `beforeAll`, `afterEach`, and `afterAll`. I wrote the following in TypeScript.

common.ts

```
// import some protractor global objects
import { browser } from 'protractor';

export let beforeMethod = () => {
  // do some method
  browser.get('/');
}

export let beforeAsyncMethod = (done) => {
  // do something that is async
  done();
}

export let afterMethod = () => {
  // do some method
}
```

login.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { beforeMethod, beforeAsyncMethod, afterMethod } from './common';

describe('login', () => {
  // do some setup
  beforeEach( beforeMethod );
  beforeEach( beforeAsyncMethod );

  it('should do your test', () => {
    // your amazing test.
  });

  afterEach( afterMethod );
});
```